# How to execute a literal in VBA?

Tags: ms-access, vba

Is there a way to execute a literal such as,

```
 UseValueKey = ExecuteMethod("Date()")
```

I want to have the variable UseValueKey return the actual date.

I am using VBA.

Any ideas?

Comment: I take it the sting literal is coming from somewhere else so you can't just use: useValueKey = Date.  What you are attempting is called a kludge.  What's driving this requirement?

Comment: Actually the value is stored in a RecordSet object for which I would allow other functions to be provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't done any VBA coding for several years, but I recall that Access VBA had an Eval() method that could be used to evaluate code represented as a string.

This [article](http://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic/answers/767159-using-eval-function-treat-string-vba-statement) gives an example of its usage.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the [Eval](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa172212(office.11).aspx) function.

Answer (score 1):

If, as indicated in the question comments, the function name is known and can be delivered as a method on a class, try looking at

```
CallByName object, routine, callType
```

where callType indicates whether the called routine is a property Get/Let/Set or a Method.

It feels a lot less kludgey (and somewhat better controlled) than fooling with code evaluation, where you may be leaving yourself open to, er, *unexpected* consequences...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm not exactly following you, but you should be able to use

```
Date
```

for example

```
UseValueKey = date
```